# How to call and execute a form using href

Tags: javascript, html, forms, paypal, href

I am designing a website using HTML5, but I am a not a pro. I have a question, that might be for beginners, but I am pulling out the few hair I still have to make this work..

Here is the question.

I have a pricelist, with the following code:

```
<div class="priceBox text-center">
<div class="inner">
<h3>Pack III</h3>

<div>
<sup>R$</sup><em>279,90</em>
</div>
<a href="#form-a" class="btn btn-primary">PagSeguro</a>
 <p></p>
<a href="#form-b" class="btn btn-primary">PayPal</a>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the form-a

```
<form action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/v2/payment.html" method="post" onsubmit="PagSeguroLightbox(this); return false;">

<input type="hidden" name="code" value="B42DF5D94242D9C884A01FA02EC30DD0" />
<input type="image" src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/209x48-comprar-assina.gif" name="submit" alt="Pague com PagSeguro - é rápido, grátis e seguro!" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.lightbox.js"></script>
```

How do I make this work, or, when I click on the button "PagSeguro" or "PayPal" the button call and execute the form-a and form-b. In this example, I place the code just for the form-a, the form-b is pretty much the same.

Thank you so much in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, in case someone have the same kind of problem. After spend a looong time with a lot of different answers and solution, I finally was able to get the correct way to do it.

**So, again, the question is. How do I submit a form from an Anchor? ( ..)**

Two simple steps will solve this conundrum:

1) Be sure the form has values for the NAME, ACTION, and METHOD properties. The NAME and ACTION properties are the only required ones, but it is a good idea to supply the METHOD also, for example:

```
<FORM NAME=Form1 ACTION="http://myServerURL/MyPage.asp" METHOD=POST>
      </FORM>
```

2) Call a one-line script from an anchor. In the script, call the submit method of the form, for example:

```
<A HREF="JAVASCRIPT:Form1.submit()"> Something </A>
```

**Note, remember that Javascript is case-sensitive, make sure that *submit* is lowercase. Also put the form in the same page from where you call the function, works better.

Thanks,

Leo

Answer (score 0):

An input type="image" only defines that image as the submit button and not as an input that can carry over a value to the server.

try the following instead:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit"><img src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/209x48-comprar-assina.gif" alt="Pague com PagSeguro - é rápido, grátis e seguro!"></button>
```